# OpenVMS packaged on a thumb drive?

Tags: linux, livecd, openvms, simulator

I am looking for OpenVMS distribution on a thumb drive for a PC. I image it would be a Linux system that automagicly starts a VAX simulator then boots OpenVMS on that. Either it would run live off of the thumb drive or it would install to the system's hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to roll your own.

1.) Install linux/BSD of your choice on the thumb drive.  I'd choose at least a 4-8Gb thumbdrive.

2.) Install SimH (easiest from a package repository)

3.) Install OpenVMS 
a.) Get media from OpenVMS hobbyist program
b.) register at eisner.decuserve.org
c.) get license from OpenVMS hobbyist program
(This is why you won't see a distribution like this floating around).
d.) install from CD rom using SimH

4.) write your script that automagically starts the simulator and loads OpenVMS